# ESERVFAIL error when i try to connect to mongodb using Moongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have real-time protection off and tried switching my internet.

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://electroAdmin:********@electroshop.hp1o7.mongodb.net/electroSuperStore?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
dbName: 'electroSuperStore'
})

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Can you share the code of the query and also setting up of pool and connect?

Comment: It works with vpn on but when vpn is off, it gives me the error                   
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://electroAdmin:electroAdmin@electroshop.hp1o7.mongodb.net/electroSuperStore?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    dbName: 'electroSuperStore'
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Database Connection is ready...')
})
.catch((err)=> {
    console.log(err);
})



//starting server at localhost:5000
app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('server is running at  http://localhost:5000');
})

Comment: You should blackout ur DB connection string, is it possible that you're querying the MongoDB before it establish a connection?

Based on the image of error, I do not see `Database Connection is ready...` logged between nodemon and the error.

Comment: Yes the issue is with the connection,  its not establishing the connection. With VPN, the connection is good to go and everything works fine but as soon as i turn the vpn off, connection is gone boom

Comment: Ah ha, it might be that your ISP or administrator is blocking that. Are you using office or school wifi?

That might explain it.

Bad thing is there isn't much you can do other than use VPN for local development. It will works out if you deploy to cloud service anyway

Comment: yes thank you. its working on home internet. i was using mobile data tho